# how to log on/off from ubuntu user to windows user without closing computer completely

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, windows-8, login-screen

i want to know if its possible to 
log on/off from ubuntu user to windows user without closing computer completely

like when in windows win+l open user logon screen then you choose your win user then login , iwanna switch 
from
 my win8 user 
to 
 ubuntu user account 
without closing user sessions completely so i can check  win8 downloads
 then write my web apps in ubuntu for example.

Comment: to clarify - are you talking about switching between operating systems? as in, you would switch out of the Ubuntu operating system, and load your Windows operating system?

Comment: yes exactly, thats what i wanna do

Comment: yah thats not possible without some very advanced internal hardware that is likely not readily available on the consumer market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not, simply because they're not running the same kernel (core). Windows and Ubuntu have very little in common.

You can try to install [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) on Ubuntu, so that you don't have to reboot your computer if you do want to use Windows. For this to work, you need to install Windows inside a virtual machine, so you will need the installation disc (or any other installation method, like an ISO file).

You can install virtualbox by executing this:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Then start VirtualBox, create a new virtual machine and start the installation procedure by selecting the source of the installation files (CD/DVD/USB/ISO).

Comment: yes i know virtualbox'es . but i have win8 and lots of things installed , applications , firefox addons, in win8. how would i left this establishments and losts of things and create a vbox from zero lots of insttallations and surrender to slow working speed in virtbox ??

Comment: im developing webapps on ubuntu , but cant leave my personel establishments too, not talking about files music videos, they are accessible from win8 to ubuntu and viceversa. but installed files are the issue, necessity for me.

Comment: The speed depends on your hardware. If your laptop is relatively new, the speed will be fine. You can try to make an image of Windows and use that in VirtualBox: http://www.labnol.org/software/create-virtual-machine-of-existing-computer/10510/

Comment: accepting the answer but, not whatt my heart desire. you provided me alternative way anyway thanksss..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have zero time switching between both operating systems, the easiest and best way is to add an extra computer and a screen. You can switch your keyboard and mouse using an USB switch: http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com/usb-switch.htm.